How to prevent text selection on double-click in JavaScript?
I'm working with a double-click event listener in JavaScript to trigger an action when a user double-clicks on certain text elements. However, I also have another event listener that responds to text selection, and the problem is that when I double-click, both events get triggered: the text is selected, and the double-click event executes.
I've tried using preventDefault(), but it didn't stop the text selection. Here's a simplified version of my code:
document.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  console.log(selection);

  if (selection.toString().length >= 0) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const selectedNode = range.startContainer.parentNode;

    if (selectedNode.tagName === 'P' && selectedNode.hasAttribute('data-audio')) {
      const audioFile = selectedNode.getAttribute('data-audio');

      // Stop the current audio if it is playing
      if (currentAudio && !currentAudio.paused) {
        currentAudio.pause();
        currentAudio.currentTime = 0; // Reset to the beginning
      }

      // Play the new audio file
      playAudio(audioFile);
    }
  }
});

function playAudio(audioFile) {
 //script to play audio
}



const toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
//this is also gets executed when double click selection occurs 
//it displays a floating menu bar
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.toString().length > 0) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();

    toolbar.style.top = `${rect.top - toolbar.offsetHeight}px`;
    toolbar.style.left = `${rect.left}px`;
    toolbar.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    toolbar.style.display = 'none';
  }

});

How can I stop the text selection from being triggered when double-clicking?
I’ve already tried event.preventDefault() without success. What other approaches can I try?
In case you need my HTML this is it
<p class = "verse" data-audio="benMahmoud-01.mp3">this is the first audio</p>
<p class = "verse" data-audio="benMahmoud-02.mp3">this is the second audio</p>
<p class = "verse" data-audio="benMahmoud-03.mp3">this is the third audio</p>


You could try user-select: none; on your verse class. Note that in Safari you still need to use -webkit-user-select: none;

Use event.stopPropagation() or event.stopImmediatePropagation() to prevent the event from being handled by the other listener.

dblclick event inherently selects any text you double click on. Being you need to be able to select the text, CSS options of making the element non select-able is not going to work. When you doubleclick, it selects text you dblclicked on, then after the second click, as your mouseup fires, you have text that is selected and the mouseup event logic is run.
To separate the two events you could add further logic in both a mousedown and your mouseup event to track if the mouse moved between the two events. Just record the event.pageX placement of your mouse to a globally scoped variable. Repeat for each event and compare the two. If you do not have a match, meaning the text caret moved during the pushing of the mouse button and releasing of the mouse button event and highlighted text. Run the code you want to fire in your mouse up event with in this conditional.
With this approach there is no need to worry about highlighted text during a doubleclick.
let downPageX = null;
let upPageX = null;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  downPageX = e.pageX;
})

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  upPageX = e.pageX;
  if(downPageX !== upPageX){
    // run the logic for highlighted text here...
  }



function playAudio(audioFile) {
 //script to play audio
}

let downPageX = null;
let upPageX = null;

const toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  downPageX = e.pageX;
  // BELOW CODE added for display ONLY NOT NEEDED
  if(toolbar.checkVisibility()){
    toolbar.querySelector('span').remove();
    toolbar.style.display = 'none';
  }
})

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  upPageX = e.pageX;
  if(downPageX !== upPageX){
    const selection = window.getSelection();

    if (selection.toString().length > 0) {
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();

      toolbar.style.top = `${rect.top - toolbar.offsetHeight}px`;
      toolbar.style.left = `${rect.left}px`;
      toolbar.style.display = 'block';
      // BELOW CODE added for display ONLY NOT NEEDED
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      toolbar.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<span> for selected text: <em>'${range}'</em></span>`);
      //-------------------------//
    } else {
      toolbar.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

});

document.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.toString().length >= 0) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const selectedNode = range.startContainer.parentNode;
    console.log(`we have double clicked on -> ${range} <- ... run double click logic now...`)
    //if (selectedNode.tagName === 'P' && selectedNode.hasAttribute('data-audio')) {
    //  const audioFile = selectedNode.getAttribute('data-audio');

      // Stop the current audio if it is playing
    //  if (currentAudio && !currentAudio.paused) {
    //    currentAudio.pause();
    //    currentAudio.currentTime = 0; // Reset to the beginning
    //  }

      // Play the new audio file
    //  playAudio(audioFile);
   // }
  }
});
#toolbar {
  display: none;
}
<p class="verse" data-audio="benMahmoud-01.mp3">this is the first audio</p>

<div id="toolbar">This is the tooltip</div>



